# Does && in c++ behave the same as && in Java?

Tags: java, c++, logical-operators

my question is essentially in the title. Basically I've learned that in Java the && operator acts like a short circuit, so that if the first condition evaluates to false it doesn't look at the rest of the statement. I assumed this was the case in c++ but I'm writing a bit of code which first checks that an index has not exceeded a list size, then compares that index in the list to another number. Something like:

```
//let's say list.size()=4;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   if(i < list.size() && list.get(i) == 5)
       //do something
   ...
}
```

That's not the exact code but it illustrates the point. I assume that since i > the list size the second half won't get evaluated. But it appears that it still does, and I believe this is causing a Seg Fault. I know I can use nested ifs but that's such an eyesore and a waste of space. Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's quite correct for either Java or C++. In my experience all conditions within a single if-condition are evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I don't know what else the problem could be. I'm going to resume banging my head against the desk...

Comment: @Brian: I would have to assume you don't have any experience with Java or C++ then.

Comment: @user391369: Please accept an answer then to close out this question.  If you can reproduce the problem with a small code example, we might be able to help you in a new question.

Comment: @Mark: it's true my experience with both is limited - I'm a C# guy primarily; all of my Java and C++ work was for undergrad and grad courses in CS.

Comment: @Brian: as a heads-up then, this holds in C# as well :-P.

Comment: just curious: in c# is && short circuits the expression?

Comment: @Mark: you may be right, though again I'm not sure. for instance I'll reliably get an error if I try the following: if(false && someArray[5]>0){...} if the index doesn't exist. Is that not what we're talking about here? I know that in the statement I gave the condition someArray[5]>0 is inconsequential given the first condition but I thought the issue had to do with the existence of the second object in the predicate.

Comment: @Brian: what error will you get?  That is what we're talking about, and you certainly should not have a runtime error occurring in the right-hand side of that expression (assuming C# has logical precedence in that > has higher precedence than &&).  Compile-time errors are obviously fair game.

Comment: @Mark: if the specified index value doesn't exist I'll get an ArgumentOutOfRange exception at runtime.

Comment: @Brian: Well, all I can say there is post a runnable example of that behaviour as a separate question, since it certainly seems to go against the docs for `&&`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(VS.71).aspx.  I don't have a C# environment handy but I'm guessing you're misrepresenting something.  Are you sure you didn't try `||`?

Comment: @Brian: that code compiles and runs fine in C#, just like it does in C++ and Java (and yes, I just tested it). I'm not sure how you managed to produce a runtime error. Is it possible that you used `&` instead of `&&` (in C#, `&` is a logical and that *doesn't* short-circuit), or that you used `||`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in C and C++ the && and || operators short-circuit.

Answer (score 4):

Shortcutting works the same in C, C++, and Java.

However, given the example code, you may get a segfault if `list` is `null`. C++ has no equivalent to Java's NullPointerException. If list might be null, you need to test for that as well.

**Updated**
The latter half of that only applies if list is a pointer. (Which is does not appear to be.) If that was the case it would look like:

```
if (list && i < list->size() && list->get(i) == 5)
```

Comment: I didn't know you could test for something being null that way. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @user391369: You can't in Java, but can in C++.  In Java you would need to make it a boolean expression (`if (list != null && ...`).

Comment: Based on the usage of `list.size()`, it appears that `list` is not a pointer in this case, so testing for null won't work.

Comment: @GBegen Good catch.  Can't believe I missed that. I know I've been solidly in Java lad for months now, but... wow. Go me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes `&&` behaves similarly in Java as in C++. It is a short circuiting operator and also a **sequence point** [in C++]. The order of evaluation of operands is well defined i.e from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

C++ && and || operators do shortcircuiting too. Be careful, maybe you put a single & and C++ is using tbe binary and operator, which is not shortcircuited. Post more relevant code if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

C++ short circuits && and || just like Java. in `if(i < list.size() && list.get(i))` , `list.get(i)` will not be evaluated if `i < list.size()` is false.

Answer (score 1):

The && and || operators short-circuit if not overloaded.  I believe they can be overloaded, however, in which case they would not short-circuit if used on types for which an overload was in effect.